# What is the possible value of: $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-ab$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a$ and $b$ are two non-zero real numbers that satisfy $ab = a - b$
What is the possible value of: $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-ab$

I found it $2b$

Is it true?

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you got that result.

Comment: plug in some numbers (e.g. $a=b=1$) and see if your result is correct in that case.

Comment: @Oбжорoв while I agree that checking some cases is a good idea I feel compelled to mention that if $a=b=1$ then $ab = 1 \neq 0 = a-b$ so it's doesn't meet the criteria. You can find some counter-examples pretty quickly though by guess-and-test.

Comment: @CyclotomicField you are absolutely right. Although my approach was correct, the example wasn't.

Comment: Please, show your work that you did to find the result.

Comment: Fun fact : the only integer solutions to the initial condition are $(0,0)$ and $(-2,2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac a b + \frac b a - ab =\\
\frac {a^2 + b^2 - (ab)^2} {ab} =\\
\frac {a^2 + b^2 - a^2 +2ab - b^2} {ab} =\\
\frac {2ab} {ab} =\\
2$$

EDIT: FWIW, here's another sequence $-$ first worth noting that $a, b \ne 0$ for otherwise the problem statement is not well defined. We have

$$
ab = a - b \iff
ab + b  = a \iff
a + 1 = \frac a b
$$

Likewise,

$$
ab = a - b \iff
a - ab = b \iff
1 - b = \frac b a
$$

So,

$$
\frac a b + \frac b a - ab =\\
a + 1 + 1 - b - ab =\\
2 + a - b - ab =\\
2
$$